# how to fill color of image with progess animation in ios?

Tags: ios, animation

I have integrate registration in my apps. registration have three pages. I want to integrate fill color of image with animation of each step.

for Example,

When i am click on Create Account. It go to first page of registration. and there is display image as below.[image]

After click on next page it go second page of Registration. but i want to filling color animation of image when enter in to second. animation is only 2 second . and in this animation first to second are make fully red with animation and it display as below image.[image]

and same as second to third and display as below image.[image]

Please help me about it.

Thanks,

Comment: Check this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sttimeslider, it might help

Comment: Here 1,2,3 are three different images

Comment: Yes , I have three different images